# ACME protocol without LetsEncrypt, using dedicated CA

Tags: authentication, certificate-authority

I have a question about the ACME protocol without using LetsEncrypt, and using our dedicated CA instead.

Can anyone enlighten me what should I consider in my client-server application which satisfies the ACME protocol which we can implement in our Network Security standard?

Comment: You might be more interested in a forum. This site here has very strict rules what types of question is allowed, `an interaction and knowledge share among us` is not one of them.

Comment: @user155462 I have edited that out. I believe it's on-topic now.

Comment: @I/tsecguy18 Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! I took the liberty of making a major edit to your question. I believe it is on-topic now. If you have done prior research, you can [edit] it into the question. On these sites, it is almost always a good idea to show prior research. Good luck, hope you'll get an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of which parts need to be secure.  It doesn't matter if others get the CSR (it does matter if they can tamper with it) or the CRT.  You are going to turn around and publicly share the certificate with everyone in order to make use of it.  You should never be transmitting the private key and the ACME protocol does not require this.

What DOES need to be secure is that you need to ensure that the challenge is not tampered with.  If a challenge is tampered with between the ACME server and the client, it would be possible for an adversary to trick the legitimate client in to answering the challenge for the attacker so that the attacker can be issued a certificate by the server for their own private key.

You can use SSL with a pinned certificate to ensure that you are actually talking to the real server when receiving the challenge they issue for your particular CSR.  This will allow establishing a secure connection with the server such that you can verify that the CSR is unaltered in flight and that the challenge provided is the one for your CSR.

Comment: That is a very nice explanation. I would like to point out my other doubt. In the _server_ ,the **self-signed RootCA** is the only trust-able resource. So when the CSR with public key and the encrypted hash is sent to the Server. How the Server will confirm that this CSR and hash belongs to them and sign it? Is there any documentation which explains me this. So that I should read it for sure. :-)

Comment: It is up to the client to only provide the CSR to a valid server (by validating the SSL connection) and only answer challenges from the valid server (similarly validated).  If the CA is not trusted by the client yet, you need some other mechanism for ensuring that the client gets the correct CA root certificate and adds it to trust.